# Add custom maven repositories to build.gradle from Cordova

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, gradle, build.gradle

I am trying to add **programmatically** a repository to my `build.gradle` file.

According to [Cordova docs](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/android/index.html#configuring-gradle) it is possible to extend `build.gradle` via a `build-extras.gradle` file that is en the same directory of `build.gradle` directory.

The problem is that the repo is not added/linked because the gradle sync stills failing.

This is my build-extras.gradle file:

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
      google()
    }
}
```

I need to add `google()` repo to my `build.gradle` for example inside this:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {

        //google() <-- here
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }

    // Switch the Android Gradle plugin version requirement depending on the
    // installed version of Gradle. This dependency is documented at
    // http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/version-compatibility
    // and https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-8143
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'
    }
}
```

But I founded the cordova docs info to extend instead edit the build.gradle

Is it possible? What would be wrong into my build-extras.gradle?

Comment: did you find the answer?

Answer (score -3):

I’m not sure what you mean with: “The problem is that the repo is not added/linked because the gradle sync stills failing.”

Aside from that, it’s important to note that `buildscript { … }` applies to the enclosing build script (file) only. In other words, the `buildscript` you add to `build-extras.gradle` only applies to this very file; likewise, the `buildscript` block added by Cordova to `build.gradle` only applies to that file. That leads to the question why you’d want to change the classpath of the build script in `build.gradle` even though you can’t change anything in that file?

Did you maybe actually want to add a repository for dependencies that are not needed in the build *script* directly but rather for compiling some Java code, for example? In that case, you’d have to declare your repository like so (i.e., *not* within a `buildscript` block):

```
repositories {
    google()
}
```

Comment: My problem is that the native sources of my app has been obtained in a gradle 4.+ environment version but this native sources will be compiled and published with a non 4.+ environment. To do this, I have to add the ‘google()’ repo into the build.gradle inside of the buildscripts -> repositories block. Is this correct?

Comment: I am developing with a gradle wrapper version > 4.x. The version  of gradle wrapper of  my customer is 2.x. The project uses Google maps library, because of this when my customer tries to sync the project on android studio it not finished and the error is 'play-services-base-license'. My customer reports to me that if add the 'google()' repo to the build.gradle it syncs correctly. I think that in gradle 4.x wrapper the dependencies of play services and other resolves automatically but in older versions of gradle not.

Comment: The `google()` repo was only introduced with Gradle 4.0 ([via](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/artifacts/dsl/RepositoryHandler.html#google--)), I’m wondering why it would work for your customer with Gradle 2.x? Anyway, I don’t know why the play-services-base-license module would need to be on the classpath of the buildscript, so I’m wondering if the suggestion from my answer works? Maybe you’ll have to provide more details of your build configuration; with the available information it’s hard to make better suggestions.

Comment: Your suggestion not works for me. After more test,  it only work on my customer if I add the repo on allprojects{ repositories{ google().........

Comment: Well … how should I have known that there are subprojects in your build which need this repository? But glad to hear that at least my guess was right that you were actually not looking for a `buildscript` repository.

Comment: Sorry but my english is not very good. This project is an Ionic project, due to some library, in my opinion Cordova Google Maps, I have to add this repository in this section, allprojects.... Is possible to do this? Thanks for your time